# The word "SQUARE"

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assuming that any arrangement of letters forms a 'word', how many 'words' of any length can be formed from the letters of the word "SQUARE"? No repeating of letters.

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Welcome  ! On this site, you need to show efforts made and difficulties faced so that we can understand how to help.

Comment: I just posted sirs, sorry if my answer was late.

Comment: Hint: There are $(6)(5)(4)$ words of length $3$.

Comment: Sir Nicolas, is 2 letter word count on this problem?

Comment: Yes, there are $(6)(5)$ of them. One letter words also count. I assume that the $0$-letter word (empty word, null word)  does not count.

Comment: 2 letter words from square.
ES / US / AE / AR / AS / ER / RE
thats 7 so 36 + 7 is 43
But if the 1 letter word is count
A is the only one letter word in square i think?
So its 43 + 1, the answer should be 44.

Answer (score 2):

Add up the following:

- The number of $1$-letter words is $\dbinom61\cdot1!=6$
- The number of $2$-letter words is $\dbinom62\cdot2!=30$
- The number of $3$-letter words is $\dbinom63\cdot3!=120$
- The number of $4$-letter words is $\dbinom64\cdot4!=360$
- The number of $5$-letter words is $\dbinom65\cdot5!=720$
- The number of $6$-letter words is $\dbinom66\cdot6!=720$

Comment: Repeat of my answer? You just flipped the factorial around in Pascal's triangle. But very clear and direct, coups for you.

Comment: @theREALyumdub: I haven't read your answer up until now (and obviously, for such a simple question, most answers will look rather identical).

Comment: That is understandable. I will leave mine up anyways but just wanted to make the observation.

Comment: why are you using binomial coefficients in the first place? I mean is the following not much more intuitive(?): 1-letter word 6 possibilities, 2-letter word $6\cdot 5$ possi., 3-letter $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ and so on...

Comment: See the wikipedia page on the binomial theorem. In general, mathematicians like to connect ideas such as binomials with other parts of math. The binomial coefficients can be easily understood in terms of pascal's teiangle

Comment: @theREALyumdub sure, the answer is correct but uses a not-so intuitive access (like yours as well), that's why I wonder. If you want to calculate the poss. of a 2-letter word, why not simply use $6\cdot 5=30$ instead of $\dbinom62\cdot2!=30$

Answer (score 0):

All the letters of "SQUARE" are distinct, so it is the permutation of every element picking all six elements, plus the permutation of every element picking 5 elements, etc. There is no need to remark about repeating letters.

Note if I pick letters out to make the words from, I get so many ways to pick the numbers, corresponding to the number of ways to pick different letters. That will be the combination series, that is, a row of pascal's triangle, multiplied by each permutation. So using n! to represent the possible permutations of n elements, and nCr to represent the combination of n things in r places, we get:

6!(6C0) + 5!(6C1) + 4!(6C2) + 3!(6C3) + 2!(6C4) + (6C5)

Note I don't go further, because pulling out 6 elements and then permuting is not helpful, since a word has to have a letter in it.

As a side remark, the above formula for arbitrary n is somehow related to $ 2^n $, but I couldn't be bothered to do the computation honestly

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be the number of words which can be formed from $n$ distinct letters.

There are $n$ choices for the first letter. The remains of the word are either empty (no letters), which can be achieved in one way, or form a word made up of the remaining $n-1$ letters, which can be done in $a_{n-1}$ ways.

So we have $a_n=n\times (1+a_{n-1})$ as a simple recurrence which can be used to compute $a_n$ for small $n$.